# How to render specific content with (location/rewrite/proxy) but not change the origin URL in Nginx?

Tags: nginx

I know something about Nginx's `location`, `rewrite` directives.

I have a file named `say_hi.html`, its path: `/opt/app`, its content:

```
# file name:  /opt/app/say_hi.html
Hi, there!
```

and I want to open this url in my browser: `http://my_site.com/to/be/removed/say_hi.html` and want to see the content

`Hi, there!`

and the URL is not changed. (e.g. not changed to : `http://my_site.com/say_hi.html` )

Can I do this in Nginx?

thanks a lot!

BTW, I have already this solution, but not satisfy my need: ( it changed the URL and return 301)

```
 server {
   listen 80 default_server;
  
   location / {
     try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
     root /opt/app/;
   }

   location ~ /to/be/removed {
     rewrite ^/abc(.*)$ $1 break;
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solve this by using `location` + `proxy pass` and a `virtual host`

step 1: identify the location and give it to a `proxy`, e.g.:

```
  location ~ /to/be/removed {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8800;
  }
```

step 2: define a proxy server:

```
server {
  # define a port
  listen 8800;

  # step 2.1： change "/abc/test" to "/test"
  location ~ /abc/test {
    root /opt/app/test_folder;   # this line must be here ,not removed.
    rewrite ^/abc(.*)$ $1 break;
  }

  # step 2.2：this is the normal way to render html/js
  location / {
    root /opt/app/test_folder;
  } 
}
```

Actually there's another solution:

re-compile the `front-end` project ( such as vue, react-js, angular) and give it an prefix.